# Convert webmercator coordinates to lat lng

Tags: maps, leaflet, coordinates, converters

Is there a way to convert webMercator coordinates to lat lng?

```
{ x: 0.524845254783345, y: 0.3454821604047296 }  => {lat: --, lng:--}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [proj4.js](http://proj4js.org/), which is designed for converting coordinates.

Projections can be defined by well known text (wkt) strings, or proj4 strings (both can be found on [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/)). The example below uses the latter option. Coordinates can be of two formats: `[x,y]` or `{x:x,y:y}`.

Here's a demo with your coordinate with projection definitions from spatialreference.org:

```js
var coordinate = { x: 0.524845254783345, y: 0.3454821604047296 };

var webMercator = "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs";

var wgs84 = "+title=WGS 84 (long/lat) +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=degrees";

var newCoord = proj4(webMercator,wgs84,coordinate);

console.log(newCoord);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.4.4/proj4.js"></script>
```

(Your coordinate is very close to [0,0], the small output values are not an error).